# wansview ip camera stream url for openCV

Tags: opencv, ip-camera

I have just bought an wansview IP camera model NCM630GB. I am able to play it video stream in browser but i am not able to open its in open CV using video capture object. I have tried different solution already present on stack overflow but the actual problem is getting url of video stream. Can anybody tell what is the videostream url of wansview IP camera or any method to find it.

Comment: Since you can view it in the browser try to check the URL there via dev tools or something.

Comment: Yes I have tried 'inspect element' in chrome but no URL to video is written there. The video stream actually installed an HYplayer plugin initially to display video. I don't have much knowledge about browsers so I thought that URL is not being shown due to that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [documentation](http://www.avacomtech.com/uploads/3/0/1/5/3015788/wansview_ncb_ip_camera_user_manual.pdf) (page 22), the url should be:

> http://IP address:port/videostream.asf?user=user name&pwd=password

Try it with VLC to see if you can get the stream. If succeed, then in OpenCV, append x.mjpg to the url, like this:

> http://IP address:port/videostream.asf?user=user
>   name&pwd=password?x.mjpg

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. But video quality is highly degraded. And opencv is giving warnings like '[h264 @ xxxxxxxx] error while deciding MB XX XX, bytestream (XX)' is there any other solution to this.

Comment: BTW the quality problem is solved in Linux. It was only happening in Visual studio.

Comment: Broken link (documentation)